# Eigen sparse matrix determinant is zero

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to compute if a sparse matrix I am operating on is positive definite. For this I am trying to use the sylvester criterion, meaning that the leading minors are positive.

To calculate the determinant of the matrix I am constructing a sparseLU solver of each block of the matrix, which can then give me the determinant of the matrix. But starting from a certain dimension (around 130*130) I am getting the result that all determinants are 0. This is not some special dimension in my problem (the matrix has blocks of 32*32) so I am believing this issue is related to some truncation algorithm applied by Eigen with determinants simply falling below some thresholds.

My search for such a mechanism has resulted in no decent results.
My matrix has dimensions of around 16k*16k and all non-zero elements are on the on the 96 elements near the diagonal.

Is any truncation mechanism implemented in Eigen and can I control its thresholds somehow?

Comment: It can be a little careless, but can't you just wait for the algorithm that requires a positive definite matrix to fail?

Comment: All sparse matrix solver available in Eigen which require the matrix to be positive definite also require the matrix to be symmetric, which mine is not

Comment: For such big matrices, even sparse, accumulation of rounding errors can be terrible. Have you tried using longer types ?

Comment: I am already using doubles and my compiler doesn't support any larger types, but @chtz gave the answer I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very likely due to underflow, i.e., the determinant is calculated as a product of lots of numbers smaller than `1.0`. If you calculate the product of 130 values around `0.5` you are near the border of what can be represented with single precision floats.

You can use the methods [`logAbsDeterminant`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html#a89e30a7df205596784a5a73f4768eaec) and [`signDeterminant`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html#a6651143e3b18fa90cfb3808b6fd23c4e) to get meaningful results.

Comment: I had already found logAbsDeterminant, but somehow overlooked signDeterminant. This is exactly what I needed, thank you